# How to get a deferred attribute value?

Tags: python, django

I need to compare two ID values to see if they match.  In this database, there are Areas, and Locations within them.  I need to check which locations are in a certain area.  Areas have an ID as the primary key, and locations have a foreign key in them pointing to area.

```
    if obj.area.id == self.id:
```

For some reason, the foreign key always returns correct values, while self.id (is inside the Area class) always returns `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03506B70>`.  I have tried Area.id, Area.pk, Area._get_pk_val, and everything using self instead of Area.  How do I pull the value out of deferred attribute?

```
    class Area(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        longitude = models.FloatField(default=0)
        latitude = models.FloatField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        def number_of_locations(self):
            count=0
            measurements.objects
            for obj in Location.objects.all():
                print (str(obj.area.id)+" vs "+str(self.id))
                if obj.area.id == self.id:
                    print("check")
                    count+=1
            return count
```

EDIT:  Finally got it to work.  Now it checks all areas instead of the one it is currently on and returns an array of all location amounts.  It's not what I originally intended but it will work.

```
        def number_of_locations(self):
        count_array = []
        count=0
        for a in Area.objects.all():
            for obj in Location.objects.all():
                #print (str(obj.area.id)+" vs "+str(a.id))
                if obj.area.id == a.id:
                    print("check")
                    count+=1
            count_array.append(count)
            count=0
        return count_array
```

Comment: do you query for `id` in `self.id`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: add your full view function/class

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: add to question with properly formatted. This code is not readable

Comment: Yeah I just thought of that.  Done.

Comment: do you want to compare all id of `Area` with all id of `Location`?

Comment: Yes.  I am checking all locations to see if they contain the same area id that is in this class.  The IDs are correct from location, but not from self.

Comment: Is area has any relationship with location like foreignkey relation?

Comment: Yes.  I specified that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by `exists()`. It will return true if this item exists in model
Try this

```
def number_of_locations(self):
    count = 0
    for obj in Location.objects.all():
        print(str(obj.area.id) + " vs " + str(self.id))
        if obj.area.id == Area.objects.filter(pk=obj.area.id).values_list('pk', flat=True).first():
            print("check")
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but that method is returning true for all comparisons whether they are equal or not.

Comment: can you check `obj.area.id` which value get

Comment: To reiterate, location foreign key values are all correct.  Its the values from within the Area class that are incorrect.
https://i.postimg.cc/6pFtmTKz/Capture.png

Comment: It also returns all true.

Comment: Sorry.  That just gave an error.
QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): True.

Comment: All true again.

Comment: I can't believe it, but I just got it to work.  It's a different output than I originally intended, but I'll post it in a moment.